# WAMP | Installing PDO drivers into PhP extensions

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, wamp, driver

WAMP is relatively new ground to me.  I have currently only done basic installations and vhosts configurations.

### Issue

I am trying to get the PDO drivers installed on my WAMP server so I can connect to SQL Server Databases. From a previous question I asked it was determined i do not have the correct drivers.

### Attempts

I have downloaded the drivers from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098) but I am still not sure which drivers I need to be using. My Apache and PhP build are as follows `Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12`

I have installed the `SQLSRV32.EXE` downloaded from the Microsoft page and put it into the PHP extensions on WAMP. a lot of pdo options now show up but they have a red warning sign above them. even though i can see these with the red warning sign I continue to get PDO drivers not found error message when I try to connect to the database.

[image]

### Resources

so you can see my current php_info I have [pasted it into my chrome here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B33eiP7abHKXOUZyeUNNZkpqOFk/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common problem, and one I've solved for a few people recently. Make sure you check the following list to ensure you have put them in place:

1. Ensure both php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll and php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll are in your /ext directory.
2. Ensure the following lines are present in your php.ini file: extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll & extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll.
3. Ensure you have installed VC++ redist located [here.](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30679) **Make sure you download and install the x86 version regardless of the architecture of your OS otherwise this will not work**.

Check these things and come back to me with an answer.

Comment: I have checked these things and it still seems to be the same. red error messages next to the extensions and the error message (image in main question). on Point (.2)The lines where not present in PHP.ini but i added them, still nothing

Comment: Just wondering why you decided to go with WAMPServer rather than XAMPP? Just an observation. There's not much difference mind (in fact WAMPServer is probably lighter and faster), just most people I've seen use XAMPP these days. Anyway, have you checked the ODBC drivers are installed on the server you're installing WAMPServer on?

Comment: testing environment set up by previous employee :) too much ahs been modified to change over at this current time :(

Comment: Small world! Shame though, you should travel o'er top, it's much sunnier in good ol' Yorkshire ;) Check the ODBC Drivers, it seems to be an issue with WAMP.

Comment: will have to have a proper look into it :) and i love yorkshire. Mate went uni at wakefield i used to live in barnsley and i go york with partner a lot :)